# Bootstrap asp.net framework begginer

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm a little new to both Bootstrap and ASP.Net.

I'm trying to use an very simple example from Bootstrap homesite
where I just throw this into `about.cshtml` file.

The Bootstrap is version 3.4.1 on the ASP.Net and I'm choosing the 3rd version of the Bootstrap example but I'm not getting any table and just 3 stacked text besides each other. Is it the wrong version or am I not able to see the mistake? What am I doing wrong?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    var $table = $('#table')

    $(function () {
        var data = [
            {
                'id': 0,
                'name': 'Item 0',
                'price': '$0'
            },
            {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'Item 1',
                'price': '$1'
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'Item 2',
                'price': '$2'
            },
            {
                'id': 3,
                'name': 'Item 3',
                'price': '$3'
            },
            {
                'id': 4,
                'name': 'Item 4',
                'price': '$4'
            },
            {
                'id': 5,
                'name': 'Item 5',
                'price': '$5'
            }
        ]
        $table.bootstrapTable({ data: data })
    })
</script>
```

[image]

My _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried to add the different versions and so on but nothing really seems to be working

Comment: Have you included jQuery and the Bootstrap Javascript libraries in your layout page? Also, check your browser's developer console for errors.

Comment: I have added the layout in the edit but cant really see what im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script tags need to be inside the `Scripts` section. Otherwise, you're trying to load them *before* the libraries they depend on.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

@section Scripts {
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var $table = $('#table')

    $(function () {
        var data = [
            {
                'id': 0,
                'name': 'Item 0',
                'price': '$0'
            },
            ...
        ]
        $table.bootstrapTable({ data: data })
    })
    </script>
}
```

If you check the developer console in your browser with your current page, you'll see errors telling you that jQuery has not been loaded.

Comment: Thank you I got it to work also with some other exampels thank you